# Facebook javascript login to PHP SDK

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using the FB facebook-php-sdk-v4-5.0-dev.zip API files.

I'm attempting to make the Facebook javascript and php SDKs work together. I have FB.login working find, I can make Graph requests, etc. Now I want to pass off the access token to my PHP code, and continue from there. I am initializing FB in javascript:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId      : appId, //my appId
        cookie     : true,  // enable cookies for session access
        xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
        version    : 'v2.2' // use version 2.2
    });
```

And now that FB in initialized, I do some other work using the API, after which I push out to my php code with:

```
window.location.replace(<my url>.php);
```

Inside my PHP application, I have the following:

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([ 'app_id' => <my app_id>,
                              'app_secret' => <my app_secret>
                              'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
                            ]);

$jsHelper = $fb->getJavaScriptHelper();
try 
{
    $accessToken = $jsHelper->getAccessToken();
} 
catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) 
{
    // When Graph returns an error
    print('Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage() );
    exit;
}
catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) 
{
    // When validation fails or other local issues
    print( 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage() );
    exit;
}

if (isset($accessToken)) 
{
    print("Logged in already");
}
else
{
    print("Not logged in");
}
```

What I see is "Not logged in". From what I can tell, no cookie is generated (I dumped out $_COOKIE at the top of my PHP file). I have also monitored the network calls, and can see no cookie coming down from Facebook on my oauth requests... which is where I would assume that such a cookie would come from.

Thanks,
Andy

Comment: Did you finally solve this ?  I have the same problem. `$jsHelper->getAccessToken()` returns null, and I don't see any facebook related cookie.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set cookie to true while initializing the javascript object. Otherwise FB Javascript Api won't store a cookie.

```
FB.init({
    appId   : '{app-id}',
    cookie  : true,
    version : 'v2.5'
});
```

Comment: Thanks! This should be more well-known.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend that you update to the v5.0.0 of the PHP SDK, or is there a specific reason you're using this outdated one?

Furthermore, have a look at the example at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_access_token_from_javascript/5.0.0

Copied sample code:

```
# /js-login.php
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '{app-id}',
  'app_secret' => '{app-secret}',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
  ]);

$helper = $fb->getJavaScriptHelper();

try {
  $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  // When Graph returns an error
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

if (! isset($accessToken)) {
  echo 'No cookie set or no OAuth data could be obtained from cookie.';
  exit;
}

// Logged in
echo '<h3>Access Token</h3>';
var_dump($accessToken->getValue());

$_SESSION['fb_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;

// User is logged in!
// You can redirect them to a members-only page.
//header('Location: https://example.com/members.php');
```

Comment: Well, I thought that I had, and that their naming scheme was whack ("v4-5.0"). I will go back and see if I can find better.  That sample code is pretty much (except for local variable names and formatting) the same as mine. But I'll look for a more up-to-date SDK.

Comment: Ok, I just followed  your link to the PHP SDK page, and clicked the link to download the v5 source code, and got the exact same file (facebook-php-sdk-v4-5.0-dev). So that isn't the problem, and I compared line-by-line, and I have the same code as the sample. So I'm missing something else.